# prove that the maximum value of a function is attained when all $x_i$'s are 0 or 1

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, summation, contest-math

> Let $0\leq x_i\leq 1$ for $1\leq i\leq n.$ Prove that the maximum value of the sum $S(x_1,\cdots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_{i+1},$ where $x_{n+1} := x_1$ is attained when all $x_i$'s are 0 or 1.

Note that $S$ is linear in each variable. I tried using induction on n and the fact that for fixed $x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n,$ $S(x_1,\cdots, x_n)\leq \max\{S(0,x_2,\cdots, x_n),S(1,x_2,\cdots, x_n)\},$ but I'm not sure how I can apply the inductive hypothesis since for instance $S(0,x_2,\cdots, x_n) = \sum_{i=2}^n x_i - \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} x_i x_{i+1}$, which doesn't equal $S(x_2,\cdots, x_n)$. It might be useful to generalize the inductive hypothesis somehow, but I'm not sure how. Also, I know the maximum is $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ and it's achieved when $(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n) = (1,0,1,0,\cdots, 1,0,0)$ if $n$ is odd and when $(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n) = (1,0,1,0,\cdots, 1,0)$ otherwise.

Comment: Use calculus. Find points where the derivative vanishes. The maximum is attained either at one of these points, or on the boundary of your domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix all variables except for $x_i$. Then $S$ is of the form $ax_i+b$ for some constant $a,b$. This function is either maximized at $x_i=0$ or $x_i=1$ (based on the sign of $a$). Repeating this for all variables finishes (no calculus needed!).